# Vector text for JavaScript Asteroids game?

Tags: javascript, game-physics, p5.js

I am fairly new to JavaScript coding (~6 months). I made [this website](http://mysite.pratt.edu/%7Egkelley/Vote/) for my master's thesis while following along with [this video from Coding Train](https://youtu.be/hacZU523FyM).

The site is basically Asteroids with a voting registration bent. The original idea was to have it so the "spaceship" can "shoot" different text and redirect the player to the Georgia voting registration site. Because of the deadline of the project, I had to pivot to a hover-over and on-click function, but is that possible? Converting the text to a vector that can be "shot at" like an asteroid?

Here is the code:

```
    let x, y;
let spacey;
var ship;
var asteroids = [];
var lasers = [];

function preload(){
  spacey = loadImage('data/spacey abrams.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  ship = new Ship();
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    asteroids.push(new Asteroid());
  }
  noCursor();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  textSize(32);
  text("Fly Space Abrams around with your mouse. If the qualifications apply to you, double click for a surprise!", 100, 100);
  textSize(16);
  text("You can also pilot the voter-empowerment ship in the middle with your arrow keys and fire lasers with your space bar. Pew pew!", 100, 150);
  fill(255);
  if ((mouseX > 200) && (mouseX < 300) && (mouseY > 200) && (mouseY < 300)){
  text("Are you a US citizen?", 200, 300);}

  if ((mouseX > 400) && (mouseX < 500) && (mouseY > 400) && (mouseY < 500)){
  text("Are you a resident of the county/precint in which you are voting?", 400, 500);}

  if ((mouseX > 600) && (mouseX < 700) && (mouseY > 600) && (mouseY < 700)){
  text("Will you be 18 on 1/5/2021?", 600, 700);}

  if ((mouseX > 800) && (mouseX < 900) && (mouseY > 800) && (mouseY < 900)){
  text("Are you not a felon?", 800, 900);}

  image(spacey, mouseX, mouseY);

  for (var i = 0; i < asteroids.length; i++) {
    if (ship.hits(asteroids[i])) {
      console.log('ooops!');
    }
    asteroids[i].render();
    asteroids[i].update();
    asteroids[i].edges();
  }

  for (var i = lasers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    lasers[i].render();
    lasers[i].update();
    if (lasers[i].offscreen()) {
      lasers.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      for (var j = asteroids.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (lasers[i].hits(asteroids[j])) {
          if (asteroids[j].r > 10) {
            var newAsteroids = asteroids[j].breakup();
            asteroids = asteroids.concat(newAsteroids);
          }
          asteroids.splice(j, 1);
          lasers.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(lasers.length);

  ship.render();
  ship.turn();
  ship.update();
  ship.edges();
  }

function keyReleased() {
  ship.setRotation(0);
  ship.boosting(false);
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    lasers.push(new Laser(ship.pos, ship.heading));
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW) {
    ship.setRotation(0.1);
  } else if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW) {
    ship.setRotation(-0.1);
  } else if (keyCode == UP_ARROW) {
    ship.boosting(true);
  }
}

function doubleClicked(){
  location.replace("https://registertovote.sos.ga.gov/GAOLVR/welcome.do#no-back-button");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `Asteroid` class renders using `beginShape()`/`endShape()` you could use `p5.Font`'s [`textToPoints()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Font/textToPoints) function:

```
let points = yourLoadedFont.textToPoints('yourTextString', yourX, yourY, yourFontSize);
```

Comment: You are correct in that the asteroid is a beginShape function. Theoretically I can see textToPoints working, but the asteroids, ship, and laser are all different constructor functions that are called in the main game code and I'm having trouble integrating textToPoints in the same way.

Like all of the other elements start as function Ship(), function Laser(), but textToPoints starts with defining the points and preloading a font. So the answer is probably obvious but I keep confusing p5js somehow.

Comment: @GraceKelley You haven't posted the classes so only working on assumptions here:1. load the font in preload(), in `setup()` you can call `textToPoints` and pass the array of points to the Asteroids (might need to change the constructor if they don't already accept a list of points for the shapes).

Comment: I figured out what was happening: You are correct, it did work that way, but I had a `push()` `pop()` around `textToPoints`. Once I removed them, it worked perfectly. Thanks!